# Signals that can be generated at the terminal

Tags: unix, signals

So i need a list of signals that can be generated at the terminals.The only ones i can think of are

```
   SIGTERM,SIGINT,SIGQUIT,SIGTSTP,SIGALRM
```

Are there any others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ kill -l
 1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL       5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT      7) SIGEMT       8) SIGFPE       9) SIGKILL     10) SIGBUS
11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGSYS      13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM
16) SIGURG      17) SIGSTOP     18) SIGTSTP     19) SIGCONT     20) SIGCHLD
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGIO       24) SIGXCPU     25) SIGXFSZ
26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF     28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGPWR      30) SIGUSR1
31) SIGUSR2     32) SIGRTMAX
```